# Why is "long double" type of a variable producing absurd output while "float" and "double" type works fine?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, long-double

All I want the following program to do is to print the product of all positive numbers less than 30 (in both exponential and non-exponential forms). It works fine when the variable `product` is declared as a `float` or a `double`,but produces totally absurd (negative) result when the type is `long double`. So please answer these two questions arising from it:

1. Why is `long double` producing totally absurd (even negative) results while `float` and  `double` types for the variable `product` producing correct results?

   I have this notion that `long double` is nothing but a "high-capacity" version of `double`, which is itself a "high-capacity" version of `float` type !!
2. Now as of the types that are producing the correct result for `product`, ie `float` and `double`, why do they produce the same output in exponential form (`%e`)  but noticeably different output for non-exponential form (`%f`) ?

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j;
    float product=1;   //Works fine
    //double product=1;  //Works fine
    //long double product=1; //Produces absurd output.
    
    
    for(j=2;j<=30;j=j+2)
    product=product*j;
    
    printf("The product of even numbers <30 is %e \n",product);
    printf("The product in non-exponential form is %f",product);
}
```

**Output for `product` as float**

```
The product of even numbers <30 is 4.284987e+16 
The product in non-exponential form is 42849875099910144.000000
```

**Output for `product` as double**

```
The product of even numbers <30 is 4.284987e+16 
The product in non-exponential form is 42849873690624000.000000
```

**Output for `product` as long double**

```
The product of even numbers <30 is -6.078565e-192 
The product in non-exponential form is -0.000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong format specifier to print it out. `float` and `double` are passed as `double` to the `printf()` function (due to default promotion rules applying to it since it's variadic), but `long double` is passed as `long double`, and you have to use the `%Lf` conversion specifier for it, else your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: There's the Hungarian to the rescue!! H2CO3,please add some more details to your answer.

Comment: @SheerFish You're welcome, but what kind of details do you want? This is pretty much all the answer.

Comment: First part of the question answered.Now the second part.Why does the non-exponential form of the output differ noticeably for float and double?

Comment: Did you notice my comment above?

Comment: @SheerFish Ah, so you asked *another* question in the meantime. Well, they differ because floating-point arithmetic is not exact.

Comment: @R.. Indeed!! `%llf` does show the same error while `%Lf` works.I verified from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ that `%lld`,`%llu`,`%llx` etc are there but nothing like `%llf`.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question: `float` has only 24 bits of significand and can only hold about ~6-7 digits of precision (the real precision is not an integer because floating-point types in computer generally use binary whereas us humans use decimal), the rest is just "garbage".

```
                  float error
precision: 1234567↓90ABCDEF digits
float:     42849875099910144.000000
double:    42849873690624000.000000
```

As you see, the difference is at the 8<sup>th</sup> digit. `double` has 53 bits of significand and could be accurate to about ~15 decimal digits which obviously means it would be more precise. But if rounded to the 6<sup>th</sup> digit (which is the default for %e) then both results in 4.284987e+16 which leads to the misconception that the result in `float` and `double` are the same even though they're not. If you print more decimal digits with `%.20e` for example, then you'll see the same difference as `%f`

If you fix the format specifier of `long double` and do more iterations then `double` will suffer the same issue if `long double` is more precise. For example if you increase the limit in your code from 30 to 50 then you'll get this

```
float:       5.204699e+32
             520469877396214593413323729928192.000000
double:      5.204698e+32
             520469842636666625085618390040576.000000
long double: 5.204698e+32
             520469842636666622693081088000000.000000
```

https://ideone.com/L6P9d6